# Spark: UDF not reading already defined value

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a function written that I am trying to apply to a dataframe via a UDF.  It applies a category based on the value in a particular column.  The function makes use of a value defined earlier in my code.  The code looks like this:

```
object myFuncs extends App {
  val sc = new SparkContext()
  val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
  val categories = List("10","20")

  def makeCategory(value:Double): String = {
    if (value < categories(0)) "< 10"
    else if (value >= categories(0) && value < categories(1)) "10 to 20"
    else ">= 10"
  }

  val myFunc = udf(makeCategory _)
  val df = sqlContext.parquetFile("hdfs:/to/my/file.parquet").withColumn("category", myFunc(col("myColumn")))
}
```

This produces a NullPointerException when it tries to read the categories variable inside the function.  This works fine if I explicitly define the categories variable inside the function.  Ultimately, I want to pass that in as an arg so I can't define it inside the function.

Any explanation why it won't read values defined outside the function in the UDF?  Any suggestion on how to make this work without explicitly defining the values in the function?  I tried using the 'lit' function and passing it as an argument but it didn't like having a list as 'lit'.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to pass the categories in the query, then it will work fine. You have to make changes into your function as

```
def makeCategory(value:Double, categoriesString : String): String = {
 val categories = categoriesString.split(",")
 if (value < categories(0)) "< 10"
 else if (value >= categories(0) && value < categories(1)) "10 to 20"
 else ">= 10"
}
```

So now you can register this function as UDT, but you have to use it like following

```
val df = sqlContext.parquetFile("hdfs:/to/my/file.parquet").withColumn("category", myFunc(col("myColumn"),"10,20"))
```

Hopefully it will help in your case.

Comment: That actually doesn't work.  Spark complains  about the second argument with a type mismatch saying it expects a org.apache.spark.sql.Column and got String.  It does however work if you use the lit function to wrap the the string argument like this: withColumn("category", myFunc(col("myColumn"), lit("10,20"))).  Spark doesn;t seem to like mixing arguments from the datafraem and from outside it.  This is one of the things I not impressed with about the Spark DSL so far.  I seem to have to declare the same values over and over and it seems seems kind of clunky.

Comment: Would like to see a much less verbose, more intuitive solution that doesn't require me to redeclare values over and over.

Comment: I've used this technique in spark query. i.e. `select * form table1 where true = contains(g1, "anotherString")`